# Google Maps. Markers array passing to function

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using Google Maps API v3.
My code takes objects (name, lat, lng, and type) from MySql database and markers their on map.
That works for me fine.
But I want to make different markers depending on them type.
So here is my markers options:

```
var iconBaznycios = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png');

var iconMuziejai = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png');

var customIcons = [];
customIcons["Baznycios"] = iconBaznycios;
customIcons["Muziejai"] = iconMuziejai;
```

And here is my function i want to pass my markers array:

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, info, type) {

  var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  bounds.extend(pt);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: pt,
             icon: customIcons[type],
             map: map,

  });
```

and maybe there is something to do with this line in php script:

```
echo ("addMarker($lat, $lng,'<b>$name</b><br/> $type');\n");
```

any ideas how to make it work my way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this PHP line needs to be changed: looks like a quote is misplaced and missing a comma.

```
echo ("addMarker($lat, $lng,'<b>$name</b><br/>', '$type');\n");
```

From my experience, `icon` inside `new google.maps.Marker` only needs the URL. It's just shorter, MarkerImage should also work.

```
var customIcons = [];
customIcons["Baznycios"] = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
customIcons["Muziejai"] = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
```

Comment: well that doesn't work for me.. in my opinion maybe it's something wrong with passing array to function

Comment: Where are you passing an array to a function? I don't see it in your question.

Comment: i need to access my array with `function addMarker`

Comment: Good point, the `addMarker` has to be able to read `customIcons`. I don't know where `customIcons` is defined. I suggest either making `customIcons` a global variable, or even better would be placing it inside `addMarker` (I guess it won't be used elsewhere).

Comment: Well it is global, since it's declared outside a function, I've tried to make it local before, doesn't work either

Comment: I'm running out of ideas, I would check if the output HTML looks correct, that means the function parameters are in place, the markers are being placed after the map is initialized. Also can you turn on your browser's console and see if there's an error?

Comment: No I mean, a live debugger. If you're using Firefox, it's an extension called Firebug. In Chrome, press F12 or Ctrl+Shift+i and select Console. In IE I think it's called Developer tools, also with F12. It will show errors as the script is reloaded and run.

Comment: `echo ("addMarker($lat, $lng,'<b>$name</b><br/> $type');\n");` i thought about that, this works fine for only one type markers, cause it's info popup, that shows marker info (name and type). I have tried changing it as you suggested, but when my map doesn't show any of markers

Comment: OH I got it! (I hope) `echo ("addMarker($lat, $lng,'<b>$name</b><br/> $type', '$type');\n");`  Quotes around `$type`!!

Comment: yeah, qoutes worked somehow... I guess it needs it cause it's a string not numbers? but I have another problem now, it shows my first type icons as i declared, but second type is shown in a default icon, not as i declared it :(

Comment: I don't know what to say. Is the function getting exactly `Muziejai` (capital M)? In fact it shouldn't even show a default icon if it's mispelled. Now you got me.

Comment: I checked it, it is written correctly. maybe function doesn't get that other type, cause `Baznycios` go first in my database, I don't know exactly how it works

Comment: I really want this to work, so I set up a simple case for comparison http://jsfiddle.net/2PANp/ On your page, go to "View Page Source" and see if your `addMarker` (2nd kind) looks like this: `addMarker(-10,-10,'<b>Muziejai</b>','Muziejai');` I tested a misspelling and it does give a default marker. It has to be exactly the same as what's written in `customIcons`.

Comment: well it really looks like that... maybe I can check somehow is that 2nd type is really passed to function?

Comment: I check what's passed with `alert`. After `bounds.extend(pt)`, you can write `alert(customIcons[type]);` to see what is really going to `icon:`.

Comment: hey, i checked my database. first type was 1-17 id, and 2nd type was 21-23, there was a gap in ids, i reentered entrys so they are in a row now, and this code works fine now! so I guess there can't be any gaps?

Comment: I have no clue about the gap. All I know about is the JavaScript and I think it should have worked fine with the gap or without a gap, because it was displaying a marker (but the default, not the one you wanted). I'm glad it's finally working!

Comment: yeah, that's strange for me too, cause markers still was shown in a map, even if there was a gap... so I will have that in mind later. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Wish I could have helped better and faster :( Have a good one and wish you the best for your project :)